# ios app for facebook feed with picture of size 600x 600

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, feed

I have an application need to post a image of size 600x600 in facbook profile timeline . With me/feed post small thumbnail is added .

Please suggest the solution for getting it resolved .

Comment: check your post image size.

Comment: I need to post bigger image , size is fixed for all the images i.e. 600x600 px . Need to post the images on timeline photos .

Comment: currently what is your image size which you are posting.

Comment: 600x600 px image need to be posted .